# Vintage Chart in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, linechart

I'm trying to display a vintage analysis line chart in Power BI. I have replicated the chart in Excel from an output of an SQL query.

Each month 0,1,..,12 is the month relative from the business date row representing +1 months from , +2 Months from ... etc.

[image]

The issue I'm having is that this dataset doesn't work in Power BI. What does the base data have to look like in order to achieve the line chart as seen in the picture?

The data I have in Power Bi is structured thusly: 
[orig] | [0] | [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNV2E.png) | [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRt7x.png) | ... | [12] | [Date]

where orig .. [12] are aggregate columns (counts) for each Date in a cumulative fashion. i.e [n] = Cts + [n-1]. This data is prepared in SQL. Power Bi does no aggregation.

Each date is supposed to be it's own line from 1 - twelve (x axis) with the values being the cumulative totals as described above.

I have made some progress on the chart... looks to be good. except it's backwards...

[image]

I have tried creating a sorting column, but get the error message that

[image]

FIXED IT!!!!! simple solution. sort ascending on the chart.

[image]

But, now, how do I stop PowerBI from displaying a flat line? Below is an example using EXCEL of what the chart should like.

[image]

Comment: What do you have in Power BI? Are the column headers correct? The series names may need to be text instead of dates, so you may want to reshape that. Can you post a screenshot of your data in Power BI?

Comment: I elaborated on the data structure

Comment: I guess what we see in the table in the first picture is what's in Power BI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using three columns. One for the date, one for the Category (0,1,2,etc.), and one for the percentage. You can accomplish this by using unpivot in the Power Query window.

Comment: It looks like that is not an option yet, in Power BI Desktop. If you need it in the Power BI Service, you could try publishing from Excel.

Answer (score 1):

In Power BI the series need to be in columns, so you need to transpose the table and make the dates the column headings. Add a column for the months numbers as text, not numbers, so it can go on the axis.